# zend_auth identity on wake

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I have a class representing my identity that contains a few pieces of information. Here is the short version.

```
class Auth_User {

    private $id;
    private $current_role;

    public function __construct($id, $current_role) {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
        $this->current_role = (string) $current_role;
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        if ( /*$current_role is not valid*/ ) {
            /*clear identity and redirect to login*/
        {
    }
}
```

My question how can I safely clear the identity and redirect to login in the wakeup method?
If I do the following it seems to run in a infinite loop.

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->clearIdentity();
$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
```

Comment: Well it should do the trick, could you provide a little more detail so that some one could give you a better solution.

Comment: I think the issue is when I call Zend_Auth::getInsance()->clearIdentity(); its calling the __wakeup function again over and over. So its infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you have a `__wakeup()` method implies that you have a `__sleep()` method.

What I would probably look at doing in this situation, would be to set an expiration on `Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth')` in the `__sleep()` method.

Then test for `__isset()` against the namespace in the `__wakeup()` method. I think this approach might work.

If you just want to clear the identity at `__sleep()` that might be a good idea as well and then just redirect to `login()` on `__wakeup()`.

Hope I'm not totally in left field...